# Is there an elegant way to swap references in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, swap, unions

Sometimes classes are referencing other classes. Implementing `std::swap()` for such classes cannot be straightforward, because it would lead to swapping of original instances instead of references. The code below illustrates this behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
   int& r_;
public:
   A(int& v) : r_(v) {}
   void swap(A& a)
   {
      std::swap(r_, a.r_);
   }
};

void test()
{
   int x = 10;
   int y = 20;

   A a(x), b(y);
   a.swap(b);

   std::cout << "x=" << x << "\n"
             << "y=" << y << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

A simple workaround with a union:

```
class A
{
   union
   {
      int& r_;
      size_t t_;
   };
public:
   A(int& v) : r_(v) {}
   void swap(A& a)
   {
      std::swap(t_, a.t_);
   }
};
```

This is effective, but not handsome. Is there a nicer way to swap two references in C++? Also how does C++ standard explain mixing references and values in one union, considering that in Stroustrup's *"The C++ Programming Language"* book a *'reference'* is defined as an *'alternative name of an object, an alias'* (p.189).

Comment: In short, don't use reference members for objects that should be fully swappable. References aren't pointers. Stop wishing they were.

Comment: +1 the question is well written and there is a clear, small and working example. However, do not use it in production code. Follow the advice of Angew

Comment: What would it mean to "swap two references"? References are aliases for objects, so anything other than swapping the objects would be weird. Thinking of references as pointers only adds confusion.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not exactly. In the same Stroustrup book, properties of references are discussed, and the idea of swapping two references does not contradict any of those properties. It's not like you assign references to each other. The number of objects and the fact that references are initialized remain invariant.

Comment: @bkxp swapping references cannot mean anything other than swapping the objects they refer to. Maybe you can elaborate on how this can have any other meaning.

Comment: "This is effective" - no it isn't. A union can't have a reference member. Perhaps your compiler supports it as a (rather dubious) extension, but it's not portable.

Comment: Maybe if `swap` become new reserved keyword

Answer (score 23):

The union trick you're using is about as non-portable as code gets. The standard places *no requirements whatsoever* on how compilers implement references. They can (and most probably do) use pointers under the hood, but this is never guaranteed. Not to mention the fact that `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(T*)` aren't required to be equal anyway.

The best answer to your problem is: don't use reference members if you need an assignable/swappable class. Just use a pointer member instead. After all, references are non-reseatable by definition, yet by wanting the class swappable, you want something reseatable. And that's a pointer.

Comment: Initially, I expected the compiler to not allow mixing references and non-references in one union. That's where the last part of my question came from.

Comment: @bkxp: The answer to that is that it's not valid, and the compiler shouldn't allow it. Mine doesn't: http://ideone.com/68kzZq

Answer (score 12):

You may use `std::reference_wrapper` instead of direct reference (which you cannot `swap`) or pointer (which may be `nullptr`). Something like:

```
class A
{
    std::reference_wrapper<int> r;
public:
   A(int& v) : r(v) {}
   void swap(A& rhs)
   {
      std::swap(r, rhs.r);
   }

   int& get() const { return r; }
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/arpLMc)

Comment: That's a nice example, thanks. It appears that the standards community have realized the need to swap references and added a workaround to C++11 contrary to the opinion expressed in some other answers here that swapping references is 'bad tone' and should be avoided. It would be interesting to look at how this was implemented. Probably it's a compiler intrinsic, since dot access operator cannot be overloaded and without dot access reference wrappers would have little usability.

Comment: @bkxp: No need of intrinsic, a simple pointer member does the job.

Comment: @bkxp This was not added for swapping references; it was added for transporting references into functions through binders in contexts like `std::bind()` and `std::thread`.

Comment: @bkxp And note that indeed, you cannot access the members of an object referenced by a reference wrapper by using `.` on the reference wrapper.

Comment: You might be able to improve this by adding `operator int`. Of course `r` is then read only outside the class.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Unless required or really useful, I prefer to be explicit with getter (And I assume that `A` may be different that a simple wrapper around `std::reference_wrapper`). But it is true that the *toy* structure may be adapted to needs.

Answer (score 5):

Your program using `union` is not legal, as you assign the reference but swap the integer than intend to use the reference again.  You can read about why, here: [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined)

An easy solution here is to use pointers instead of references.  Then everything will work smoothly, with no special code.  If you really don't like this, perhaps you can use `boost::optional<int&>` instead of plain references, but I would struggle to see how that'd be better.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you would like to do, if I understand your example, is to rebind references. This you cannot do in C++. You can either swap the *values* in the referred to objects, or you can use pointers.